# Incorrect folder name created when using cp command in bash

Tags: shell-script, cp, tilde

I would like to copy a file from one location to another. When I use the `cp` command in a terminal it works well, for example I use the following command:

```
cp -r projects/Test/ projects/Personal/
```

This leads to a creation of the folder `Test` in the folder `Personal` containing all contents of `Test` in the folder `projects`. However when I execute the same line in a bash file, instead of having a folder named `Test` in `Personal` I have a folder named `~`. The contents of the file are correct.

Would you know how I could have the folder named `Test` instead of `~`? This is the code of my bash file:

```
#!/bin/sh
cp -r projects/Test/ projects/Personal/
```

Comment: `#!/bin/bash` is best to use, but a `~`? Strange.  Separate the shebang from the command. Two lines, not one.

Comment: Hello and welcome to unix.se . What environment are you using? (linux? another unix ? something else?). And, if you want to use bash constructs somewhere in the script, change the 1st line of the script to : `#!/usr/bin/env bash` to have it run with bash instead of sh (or bash in "sh compatible" mode)

Comment: The tilde is special in the shell in that it's code for the user's home directory. For `cp`, it only comes up with the backup options (e.g. `cp --backup foo.txt bar.txt` effectively renames `bar.txt` to `bar.txt~` and then does the copy). How it could produce a file named just `~`, that's harder to understand. I think this would be a case where it would be useful to see _exactly_ the files before and after, and the exact commands used. Better, a set of commands that could be used to replicate the issue, starting from creating the files, etc. You can [edit] your question from the link below it.

Comment: It is unclear what "I have a folder named with a tilde sign" means. Does it mean you have a directory called `something~` or just `~`? Did you run the `cp` command against the same target directory several times?

Comment: The name of the folder is "~", that is, the tilde only.

Comment: I tried #!/usr/bin/env bash and it doesn't work

Comment: No, there is nothing bash specific in your script, so using bash wouldn't make a difference. Can you please [edit] your question and show us how you run this and an `ls` before and after showing the result? And please also tell us what operating system you are using. What you describe is very strange so I suspect there must be something more going on.

Comment: Your shebang is causing the script to be run under `/bin/sh` but your question refers to `bash`. Which shell are you intending to use?

Comment: i think what may be mistaken for the result here is the "~" specified in prompt, indicating the working directory to be the home directory